# I'm trying to make a work command in Discord.py where you can earn money by answering a math question but i cant get it to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Okay so im using the SQLite database for this bot currency system, and i am trying to make a new command where it would give you a math problem and if you answer it correct you earn money. Right now my problem is that even if i type the correct answer it would tell me that im wrong. This is my code:

```
def check(author):
    def inner_check(message):
        if message.author != author:
            return False
        try:
            int(message.content)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return inner_check


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def work(ctx):
    USER_ID = ctx.message.author.id
    no1 = random.randint(1,1000)
    no2 = random.randint(1,1000)
    answer = no1 + no2
    await ctx.send(f'What is **{no1}** + **{no2}**?')
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author), timeout=None)
    if msg.content == answer:
        SQL.execute('update Accounts set balance = balance + ? where user_id = ?', (100, USER_ID))
        await ctx.send(f'Good work, {ctx.message.author.mention}. You earned 100 {C_NAME}')
    else:
        SQL.execute('update Accounts set balance = balance - ? where user_id = ?', (100, USER_ID))
        await ctx.send(f"Terrible work, {ctx.message.author.mention}. I'm cutting your paycheck and you lost 100 {C_NAME}")
```

Comment: You're checking string against int. Message content is always a string.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
if msg.content == answer:
```

Replace `msg.content` with `int(msg.content)` or `answer` with `str(answer)`.

If the `answer` is correct, we will return good work.